# Airflow subdag shows success while its tasks are skipped

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a subdag that uses a sensor operator which contains a `soft_fail=true` , in order to skip instead of failing the task.

It works well, except that the status of the whole subdag is shown as "succeeded" instead of "skipped" which could be misleading when monitoring the flow, as I wouldn't know if the file has been found, or simply skipped. Any thoughts on how to make the subdag status inherit the subtasks' status?

[image: execution_flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "skipped" status isn't a failure though, you requested *not* to execute a task and it did just that. Also think about what the opposite would be, a user being surprised that their run had failed just because Airflow did as they asked and skipped all the tasks.

This issue regarding the skipped status has been covered before. For example, it was [reported in 1.8.0](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/2195) and [fixed in 1.8.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-719), but in later versions this fix [was not propagated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5189).

You could open an issue and request the change by selecting *Reference in new issue* in the [three dots of this link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dagrun.py#L347-L353).

Comment: Oh I don't want it to be "failed" I want it to be "skipped"

Comment: But the run _wasn't skipped_, just the tasks. At least that's the logic that's written up here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dagrun.py#L347-L353 -- you could open an issue and request the change, I could see an argument for it.